# Why there is checked and unchecked exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)
>   [Why are exceptions named checked and unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104251/why-are-exceptions-named-checked-and-unchecked)

Why is the two exception types in Java named "checked" and "unchecked"? What is the reason behind choosing this type of exceptions ?

Comment: Have you used search before asking?

Comment: At least you should google first then post question here.

Comment: I just found this post by Googling it.

Answer (score 3):

Checked exceptions extend `java.lang.Exception`, while unchecked exceptions extend `java.lang.RuntimeException`, or `java.lang.Error`.

`Exception` extends `java.lang.Throwable`, while `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, and `Error`, like `Exception`, extends `java.lang.Throwable`.

When deciding whether you should be using a checked vs. unchecked exception, always remember these rules:

- `Exception`S are cases an application would want to handle.
- `RuntimeException`S are cases you (usually) can't handle, due to programming error. You shouldn't catch `RuntimeException`S, they should be targeted in your unit testing, and fixed in your production code.
- `Error`S are cases you can't handle because of critical errors, such as system problems (e.g. file system has failed). You shouldn't ever throw, catch or subclass an `Error`, unless you're building something such as a compiler for the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

The class `RuntimeException` and its subclasses, and the class `Error` and its subclasses are *unchecked exceptions classes*.**The compiler doesn’t forces them to be declared in the throws clause.** All the other exception classes that are part of `Throwable` hierarchy are *checked exceptions.*

*unchecked exception classes* are exempted from compile-time checking in java because they can occur at many points in the program and recovery from them is difficult or impossible. They also depend on the logic of the programmer. For example the `OutOfMemory Exception` is thrown when JVM cannot allocate any more memory to the program