# Throwing custom exceptions in Java versus built in exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I'm a little confused because I want to be able to throw a custom exception in Java. To do this inside a function, I have to add `throws MyException` to the header of the function.

And then anything that calls that function in turn must add `throws MyException` or have a try-catch block. But why is this?

For example, when creating a Stack in java and calling the pop function, I don't have to have a try-catch and yet the pop method in Java throws a `NoSuchElementException` (or w/e it is) if there isn't an element on the stack.

Comment: You absolutely, totally, completely want to throw your own, "checked" exception.  Checked exceptions are Good.  "Advertising" the exceptions your method can throw as a standard part of the method signature is Good.  "Overloading" system, unchecked exceptions for your own use is Bad.  Don't do it :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html and more specifically, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: @paulsm4 "The price of checked exceptions is an Open/Closed Principle violation. If you throw a checked exception from a method in your code and the catch is three levels above, you must declare that exception in the signature of each method between you and the catch. This means that a change at a low level of the software can force signature changes on many higher levels." —Robert C. Martin, «Clean Code», page 107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` is a `RuntimeException` (un-checked exception) and we don't need to handle or declare `RuntimeException`S, thus the compiler wont complain, but instead throw it at runtime.

In the case of checked exceptions i.e., all the exceptions which are not subtypes of `RuntimeException`, the compiler will check for a suitable `catch` clause, enabling the program to continue its course of execution, after performing the operations within the `catch`; to do this, you need to handle them using `try/catch` blocks or declare them using the `throws` clause - delegating the responsibility of handling the exception higher up the call chain. If your custom exception is not a `RuntimeException` rules of checked exceptions apply to your custom exception as well.

> Checked exceptions ---> Forced by the compiler to handle or propagate
>
> Un-checked exceptions ---> Not checked by the compiler thus appears at runtime

Comment: so what should I extend to make my own exceptions that don't reuire me to add this 'throws exceptoin' stuff

Comment: @CodeGuy just extend your custom exception with RunTimeException.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR, You mean `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 3):

Java has so called checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions. A checked exception must be declared in method signature, an unchecked exception does not need to be declared.

If you want to define an unchecked exception yourself derive it from `RuntimeException` insted of `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to throw or try-catch all checked Exceptions , its not required for `RunTimeException` and exception that you are talking about is a RuntimeException

Comment: So what do I extend in order to make an exceptoin that I dont have to use try-catch for?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797705/why-there-is-checked-and-unchecked-exception-in-java/13797913#13797913) question.

As a general rule of thumb, when deciding whether or not to create a custom exception class, I try and use the built-in exception classes as much as possible, where it makes sense to do so, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`, etc.

Here is an example of how to create a custom `RuntimeException`, which, as you have discovered, will not require a `try/catch/finally` block, or a `throws` clause.

```
public class MyRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyRuntimeException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyRuntimeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public void go(int val) {
        if(val <= 0) throw new MyRuntimeException("Val must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```