# Why is try/catch needed in some cases but not others?

Tags: java, exception

I've been doing some pure Java development recently, and I'm using an external lib that exposes a small number of methods, each of which have the possibility of throwing an `Exception`.

Eclipse won't let me compile my program unless I wrap each of those calls in a `try-catch` block. So far, no big deal.

Then I noticed some things, like `ArrayList.add()`, which throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. How is it that I can call something like this without needing to wrap it in a `try..catch`? Obv, in this particular case, it would be incredibly irritating if you had to do it each time, but how and why is `try-catch` enforced in some situations, but not others?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Please! Do some research on the net before even posting a question!

Comment: Specifically, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: take a look at [java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) or [why-are-exceptions-named-checked-and-unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104251/why-are-exceptions-named-checked-and-unchecked)

Comment: thanks for all the links guys - i didn't realise java had 2 types of exceptions. i guess this is a pretty trivial matter when you're familiar with the language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Unchecked** exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) (subclasses of `Error` or `RuntimeException`) need no `try..catch` block, and when there is no `try...catch`, the method need not  to declare itself to be `throws` (you can, of course, and some consider declaring `throws` to be a good practice) . On the other hand, **checked** ones do need the `try...catch`, or declares `throws`.

Comment: i think your answer is clear but provide me some examples please..

Answer (score 3):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is an *unchecked* exception, i.e. it extends `RuntimeException` or `Error`, or sub class of either, therefore a try/catch block is unnecessary. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html):

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement. All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses.

In contrast, checked exceptions require a `try/catch` block otherwise a compiler error will result.